# Sequelize - order and exclude

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have a table of items with foreign keys for two tables, and I try to do FindAll with order, limit, exclude and include, something like this:

```
Items.findAll({
    order: [['creationDate', 'DESC']],
    limit: 10,
    include: [
        {
            model: Artists,
            required: false,
            attributes: ['id', 'name',]
        },
        {
            model: Albums,
            required: false,
        },
    ],
    attributes: { exclude: ['creationDate'] }
})
```

But I get an error:

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: (conn = 837, no: 1054, SQLState: 42S22) Unknown column 'Items.creationDate' in 'order clause'
```

If I delete this line:

```
    attributes: { exclude: ['creationDate'] }
```

The error disappears.

What should I do to enable the query with the desired attributes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to be a bug in sequelize..

Comment: try adding `subQuery: false` to `findAll`.  It might work with no sub-query.

Comment: @Emma Thanks! it works! Can you explain what this does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll` with `include` tries to combine data from multiple tables. In SQL, Subqueries and JOIN both achieves this use case. However, there is a slight difference in how data is combined and that what you are seeing here. By default, Sequelize generates Subqueries for `findAll` + `include` and `subQuery` params is to tell Sequelize use Subquery (`true`) or JOIN (`false`).

For more about Subqueries vs JOIN: [https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-join-and-subquery/#:~:text=Joins%20versus%20Subqueries,tables%20into%20a%20single%20result.&text=Subqueries%20can%20be%20used%20to,for%20use%20in%20a%20query](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-join-and-subquery/#:%7E:text=Joins%20versus%20Subqueries,tables%20into%20a%20single%20result.&text=Subqueries%20can%20be%20used%20to,for%20use%20in%20a%20query)

Back to Sequelize,

`subQuery: true` (default)

This will generate SQL like following

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ...(attributes except creationDate) FROM `Items` ...)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Artists` ...
...
ORDER BY `Items`.`creationDate` DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

This SQL doesn't work, since nested Subquery is executed first and the Subquery is excluding `creationDate` and when main SQL with `ORDER` is executed, `creationDate` does not exist.

Then if you turn off Subquery.

`subQuery: false`

This will generate SQL like following

```sql
SELECT ... (Artist's, Album's attributes and Item's attributes except creationDate) 
FROM `Items`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Artists` ...
...
ORDER BY `Items`.`creationDate` DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

This will work because this won't filter attributes when `ORDER` is executed and `exclude` happens at top level.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the declaration, You saved my time.